# looping over pandas dataframe with 15000 records is extremely slow, takes 72 seconds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame containing 15000 records and 20 columns, read from an Excel file. Reading the Excel file into the DataFrame takes about 4.13 seconds, using this code. The pandas version on my system is 2.0.2.

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path, sheet_name='Sheet 1', header=[
                         2, 3]).astype(object).replace(np.nan, 'None')
```

I am looping over the DataFrame using a `for` loop over `iloc` and building a dictionary with the column names as the keys of the dictionary, but with different names. For example:

```
data = []
for i in df.iloc:
    mydict = {}
    mydict['col1'] = i['Column 1 Name'].values[0]
    mydict['col2'] = i['Column 2 Name'].values[0]

    mydict['doc_date'] = datetime.datetime.strftime(i['Doc Details']['Doc Date'], r'%d-%m-%Y') \
        if isinstance(i['Doc Details']['Doc Date'], datetime.datetime) \
        else i['Doc Details']['Doc Date'].replace('/', '-')


    # 17 more columns

    data.append(mydict)
```

The for loop is taking about 72 seconds.

What is a faster way of looping over the DataFrame and building the dictionary? The for loop does not have any processing for any of the columns, other than changing the key names for dictionary and using an if condition to read a date time column.

Why should the for loop take 72 seconds when the same number of records are read by the pandas library in just 4 seconds?

EDIT 1:

The required output or transformation is a list of dictionary objects. Each dictionary object will have the key: value pairs for all the columns of one row. The list will have as many dictionary objects as the number of rows.

EDIT 2:

If my Excel is like this:

```
Col 1   Col B   Col C
0       0       0
1       1       1
2       2       2
3       3       3
4       4       4
```

I need the output like this:

```
[
    {'mycol1': '0', 'mycol2': '0', 'mycol3': '0'
    },
    {'mycol1': '1', 'mycol2': '1', 'mycol3': '1'
    },
    {'mycol1': '2', 'mycol2': '2', 'mycol3': '2'
    },
    {'mycol1': '3', 'mycol2': '3', 'mycol3': '3'
    },
    {'mycol1': '4', 'mycol2': '4', 'mycol3': '4'
    }
]
```

Notice that each dictionary object has the column keys, but with different names than the column names in the Excel.

Its a bad code I have inherited from the previous coder. My job is to improve the speed when the dataframe has several thousand rows. I do not want to change the contract between the frontend and the backend of the web app at this point, because that will require extensive changes.

Comment: Why `mydict = {}` is located in the loop? Are you sure?

Comment: Because the requirement is to have a dictionary for each row. Its a bad code that I have inherited from the previous coder. My job is to improve the speed. I do not want to change the contract between the frontend and the backend of the web app at this point, because that will require extensive changes.

Comment: Did you try `df.to_dict('records')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `df.to_dict('records')`:

```
dmap = {'A': 'mycol1', 'B': 'mycol2', 'C': 'mycol3'}
out = df.rename(columns=dmap).to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
[{'mycol1': 0, 'mycol2': 0, 'mycol3': 0},
 {'mycol1': 1, 'mycol2': 1, 'mycol3': 1},
 {'mycol1': 2, 'mycol2': 2, 'mycol3': 2},
 {'mycol1': 3, 'mycol2': 3, 'mycol3': 3},
 {'mycol1': 4, 'mycol2': 4, 'mycol3': 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks. This is quite neat and clean code. In my actual code which I posted in my question, I have 2 header rows - rows 2 and 3. Somehow the rename is not working using df.rename if I pass a dict like this: `dmap = {'A': 'mycol1', 'B': 'mycol2', 'C': 'mycol3'}`
Except for the column renaming, the output is in the desired structure of list of dictionary objects

Comment: I will post a separate question for column renaming when the Excel file has multiple header columns, and post the link to that question here. Thanks!

Comment: @AllSolutions What does this vectorized solution reduce your runtime down to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(5),'B':np.arange(5),'C':np.arange(5)})
print(df)

    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4

# Transpose the dataframe then create 
list(df.T.to_dict().values())

[{'A': 0, 'B': 0, 'C': 0},
 {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1},
 {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2},
 {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 3},
 {'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 4}]
```

Comment: No, I am trying to do this:
[{'A': '0', 'B': '0', 'C': '0'}, {'A': '1', 'B': '1', 'C': '1'}, {'A': '2', 'B': '2', 'C': '2'}, {'A': '3', 'B': '3', 'C': '3'}, {'A': '4', 'B': '4', 'C': '4'}]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example provided, maybe you can try to use list comprehension. Something like:

```
[{'mycol1': str(val1), 'mycol2': str(val2), 'mycol3': str(val3)} for val1, val2, val3 in zip(df['Col 1'], df['Col B'], df['Col C'])]
```

Comment: This also works, but after knowing about the `df.to_dict('records')`, I think that is the best approach for my current requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I compared a slightly modified version of [Himanshu Panwar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76420995/16880681) (to comply with what was asked in OP's question), Using List comprehension (based on [Anastasiya-Romanova's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421132/16880681)) and [Corralien's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76421146/16880681):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col A': np.arange(5000),
    'Col B': np.arange(5000),
    'Col C': np.arange(5000),
    })
    
print(df)

dmap = {'Col A': 'mycol1', 'Col B': 'mycol2', 'Col C': 'mycol3'}
new_names = ['mycol1', 'mycol2', 'mycol3']

#Himanshu Panwar's solution
t_start = perf_counter()
new_df1 = list(df.rename(columns=dmap).T.to_dict().values())
t_end = perf_counter()
Himanshu_Panwar_time = t_end-t_start


#List comprehension (Based on Anastasiya-Romanova's solution)
perf_counter()
new_df2 = [{new_names[ii]: value for ii, value in enumerate(row)} for row in zip(df['Col A'], df['Col B'], df['Col C'])]
t_end = perf_counter()
List_comprehension_time = t_end-t_start

#Corralien's solution
perf_counter()
new_df3 = df.rename(columns=dmap).to_dict('records')
t_end = perf_counter()
Corralien_time = t_end-t_start

print("\n", new_df1==new_df2==new_df3)
print("Himanshu Panwar's solution :", Himanshu_Panwar_time)
print("List comprehension (Based on Anastasiya-Romanova's solution) :", List_comprehension_time)
print("Corralien's solution :", Corralien_time)
```

Outputs:

```
      Col A  Col B  Col C
0         0      0      0
1         1      1      1
2         2      2      2
3         3      3      3
4         4      4      4
...     ...    ...    ...
4995   4995   4995   4995
4996   4996   4996   4996
4997   4997   4997   4997
4998   4998   4998   4998
4999   4999   4999   4999

[5000 rows x 3 columns]

 True
Himanshu Panwar's solution : 0.3294021999463439
List comprehension (Based on Anastasiya-Romanova's solution) : 0.33864239999093115
Corralien's solution : 0.36161809996701777
```

Comment: Interesting but the fastest solution doesn't give the expected result and the second fastest solution is a pain to write for 20 columns (but this can be enhanced) :)

Answer (score 1):

Using plain for-loops in python for big data processing is never a good idea. The for-loop has a lot of overhead that slows down the processing by multiple orders of magnitude.

To convert a DataFrame into a dict, use the built-in pandas function [to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), which will take a couple of milliseconds.

Do any other transformations (like the datetime processing) in the DataFrame beforehand. The conversion to dict should be the last step.

If you want to transform your data in the way you said in your edited post, you can do:

```
d = {"mycol1":[0,1,2], "mycol2":[3,4,5]}
r = []
for i in range(len(list(d.values())[0])):
    r.append(dict(zip(
        list(d.keys()), 
        [a[i] for a in list(d.values())])
    ))
# returns [{'mycol1': 0, 'mycol2': 3}, {'mycol1': 1, 'mycol2': 4}, {'mycol1': 2, 'mycol2': 5}]
```

This is very messy, because dicts are not made for data manipulating like this, but it works.

Comment: alright, but how do I get a list of dictionary objects as explained in my edited question.

Comment: check my edited answer, does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.set_index('col1').to_dict('dict')
```

Comment: I need a list of dictionary objects. The list will have as many dictionary objects as the number of rows. Each dictionary object will contain the key-value pair for one row of the DataFrame. I updated my question to make it more clear.